# Does [tag:algorithm] serve any purpose?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The tag wiki for [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) consists of a summary:

> This challenge is intended to be solved by using, creating, or resolving some processing algorithm.

and a detailed explanation:

> This challenge involves [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm).

At first glance this seems to be about as useful as tagging questions [programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming). One can just about make a case that questions which can be answered by a program consisting of a single literal don't deserve the tag, but we have more than enough of those questions already.

Does [algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) serve any purpose?

Answer (score 11):

No, it's completely pointless, but to avoid manually retagging and bumping 139 questions we should ask the mods to nuke it.

Comment: We can't make tags go boom; only SE employees can do that. Once it's clear that nobody wants the tag, I'll ping someone in the SE team to get rid of it.

Comment: Well, if this isn't a consensus, I don't know what is. I've asked to get the tag burninated, so it should be gone soon.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Burninated]

But note the 7 [untagged](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions.