# Do we need the [function] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that [20 questions are tagged [function]](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function). Looking at the questions themselves, they don't seem to have anything drastically different from other questions.

The tag wiki reads:

> For challenges that ask for a function or involve functions in some way. (Also known as methods or subroutines.)

Doesn't programming involve functions (nearly) all the time? I think the situation is the same as the one with [[algorithm]](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/does-tagalgorithm-serve-any-purpose) - the tag is far too generic and could be applied to almost any question, because any question can be solved with a function, and most questions allow functions as answers anyway. It is more useful to use tags that refer to specific types of function (e.g. [recursion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursion)).

**Should we burninate [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function)?**

Comment: I could see the use of the tag for challenges which are specifically about functional programming or where you need to *handle* functions, but I don't think it should be used for challenges where its sole purpose is to indicate that the challenge asks for a function (instead of a full program). (In that case [tag:functions] might be a better name though.) I think it's also very valid on the tips question from yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

No, we don't need the [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) tag. It is not very useful, and it looks like a meta tag to me, and those tags should be removed.

> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/
>
> From this point on, meta-tagging is explicitly discouraged.
>
> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

Of course, many tags would not work as only tag here on PPCG because we always need a winning criterion, but if we would ignore that, [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) would still be useless as the only tag on a question, so I'd say we don't need it.

Answer (score 3):

I did the usual: have a look at all the challenges.

I agree that using the tag for challenges which request a function (instead of a program) is useless. And this is how *most* challenges used the tag.

But there is a valid use case for having such a tag: for all challenges that actual *deal with* functions (as objects), e.g. challenges about higher-order functions or which are otherwise related to functional programming or [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle)s relating to functions. This is no different from the [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) or [number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number) tags.

So far, there are two challenges like this (with the tag):

- [Call a method without calling it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22469/8478)
- [Golfed fixed point combinator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1064/golfed-fixed-point-combinator)

Additionally, it's a good tag to have for tips questions about functions in particular. There is one of those so far:

- [JavaScript: Tricks to shorten onkeydown, setInterval etc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40093/8478)

We should keep a tag for these cases, but I wouldn't be opposed to making a new one called [functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) instead (note the plural). Otherwise, I suggest that we rewrite the tag wiki and excerpt for [function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function) tag, to clarify that it should *not* be used, just because the challenge asks for a function - and then remove the tag from the other 17 questions, and leave it on the three mentioned above.

As Peter mentioned, there's already a [functional-programming](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) tag. We could either use that instead of [functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) (although the latter is probably a bit more general), or we could also subsume those four questions under a new [functions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) tag. In any case, I'd rather not have both, because it will lead to no end of confusion about which tag to choose for some questions.

Comment: The fixed-point combinator one could be tagged [tag:functional-programming] instead. That tag already exists and should be a bit less confusing.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah yeah, that was another thought I had, but I figured there might be some challenges which deal with functions but aren't a strictly about "function programming" as that, so I suggested a slightly more generic [tag:functions] tag - and having both will probably lead to more confusion than anything else.

Comment: Does that mean that you also want to remove [tag:functional-programming]? If so, you should probably edit the answer to mention it.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Possibly. I've clarified my position on that.