# Should tags be plural or singular?

Tags: discussion, policy, tags

As part of [The Great Tagging Survey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4884/8478), I've noticed that the pluralisation of our tags is a bit inconsistent. The following lists all tags that refer to some kind of object that is dealt with in the corresponding challenges.

### Singular

[number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number)[string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string)[game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game)[sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequence)[regular-expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression)[date](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date)[grid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grid)[fractal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractal)[function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function)[palindrome](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palindrome)[word](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word)[board-game](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/board-game)[animation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)[subsequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subsequence)[markov-chain](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markov-chain)

### Plural

[primes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/primes)[graphs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphs)[permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutations)[logic-gates](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-gates)[data-structures](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures)[complex-numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers)[roman-numerals](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman-numerals)[cellular-automata](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cellular-automata)[anagrams](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anagrams)[grammars](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammars)

This is probably not a huge deal, but I think it would be nicer if this was consistent. I don't know if devs can rename tags (although I think they can since they can also delete them), but maybe we want to at least set up a guideline for future tags?

I'll add a few answers, please vote according to your preference or add your own answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Whichever one sounds better

The tag `roman-numeral` would sound funny as this phrase is nearly always used in the plural. On the other hand, no one in his right mind would prefer `markov-chains` to `markov-chain`.

Comment: +1. I think plurality it should be determined on a per-tag basis.

Comment: `roman-numeral` doesn’t sound weird…

Answer (score 2):

## Tags should be plural, please fix the existing ones if possible

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 1):

## Tags should be singular, please fix the existing ones if possible

Answer (score 1):

## Future tags should be plural, but don't fix the existing ones

Comment: +1 from me (can't vote)

Answer (score 0):

## Future tags should be singular, but don't fix the existing ones

Answer (score 0):

## It doesn't matter. Flip a coin for all I care!

Comment: -1 from me (can't vote)